# A master url must be set to your configuration (Spark scala on AWS)

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark

[image: This is what I ran (in scala spark)]

This is what I wrote via intellij. I plan on eventually writing larger spark scala files.

Anyways, I uploaded it on an AWS cluster that I had made. The `"master"` line, line 11 was `"master("local")"`. I ran into this error

The second picture is the error that was returned by AWS when it did not run successfully. i changed **line 11** to `"yarn"` instead of `local` (see the first picture for its current state)

It still is returning the same error. I put in the following flags when I uploaded it manually
 `--steps Type=CUSTOM_JAR,Name="SimpleApp"`

It worked two weeks ago. My friend did almost the exact same thing as me. I am not sure why it isn't working.

I am looking for both a brief explanation and an answer. Looks like I need a little more knowledge on how spark works.

I am working with amazon EMR.
[image: the error AWS gave]

Comment: 'line 11 was "master("local")". I ran into this error'. On the image it's "yarn" - why did you add the image if it's misleading...

Comment: please copy code part and remove the snapshot image

Comment: @Ashwin Iyer I just added examples how can you set master to SparkConf

Answer (score 1):

I think on the line 9 you are creating SparkContext with "old way" approach in spark 1.6.x and older version - you **need to set master** in  default **configuration file** (usually location `conf/spark-defaults.conf`) or pass it to **spark-submit** (it is required in `new SparkConf()`)...

On line  10 you are creating "spark" context with SparkSesion which is approach in `spark 2.0.0`. So in my opinion your problem is line num. 9 and I think you should remove it and work with SparkSesion or set reqiered configuration for `SparkContext` In case when you need `sc`.

You can access to sparkContext with `sparkSession.sparkContext();`

If you still want to use `SparkConf` you need to define master programatically:

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
                    .setAppName("spark-application-name")
                    .setMaster("local[4]")
                    .set("spark.executor.memory","512m");
```

or with declarative approach in `conf/spark-defaults.conf`

```
spark.master            local[4]
spark.executor.memory   512m
```

or simply at runtime:

```
./bin/spark-submit --name "spark-application-name" --master local[4] --executor-memory 512m your-spark-job.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the below code:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("spark://ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:xxxx").appName("example").getOrCreate()
```

you need to provide the proper link to your aws cluster.